# How can I have Google App Invites recognize the device and send you to the appropriate store? App Store vs Google Play?

Tags: google-app-invites

I plan on implementing Google App Invites on our iOS and Android app.  What I have not been able to figure out yet is will an iOS user be able to invite an Android user and vice versa - and is there a way to have the invite recognize which device the recipient is using and send to the correct store?

Answer (score 2):

You can send invites cross platform between Android and iOS, even have a mixture among recipients in a single invite.

For app invites to find the correct cross platform app to install the mapping must be defined in the developers console (console.developers.google.com) by putting them in the same project.

Comment: could you please elaborate a little bit more on this one? where to add the second app in dev console?

Comment: Select (or create) your project in the console.developers.google.com, then create Credentials for each client, which assigns a client ID. From the drawer menu select API Manager > Credentials > Credentials. In the New Credentials dropdown, select OAuth client ID, and add both your iOS and Android app by entering the identifying data requested, one at a time. If you only have 1 client of each type (iOS, Android), no need to copy the Client ID. However, if you register more than one of either type, then disambiguate that type in the invitation builder api, setOtherPlatformsTargetApplication().

Answer (score 0):

When sending an invite from an Android app the link that is generated and sent in the invite is a link to the play store. So currently, I'm guessing Android users can only invite Android users.

The link generated from an iOS app is to a webpage, so theoretically it's possible to identify the OS via user agent and send to the correct store. Currently that does not happen though, the page redirects to iTunes when opened on Android as well.

So, it seems that currently you can only send an invite to the store corresponding to your OS,  i.e. Android users can only send an invite to the play store and iOS users to the app store.